# ORMLite - multiple indexes with the same column

Tags: java, android, ormlite

In ORMLite is it possible to have the same column participate in multiple indexes?
The `@DatabaseField(index=...)` annotation seems to only allow one index per field.

For example I may have a class:

```
public class PhoneCall{
    @DatabaseField
    public Date timestamp;
    @DatabaseField
    public String from;
    @DatabaseField
    public String to;
}
```

And my queries are always done first by timestamp, and then by 'from' or by 'to'.

In such case I need two combined indexes:

- index1: (timestamp, from)
- index2: (timestamp, to)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc of [`DatabaseField`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html)

```
    /**
     * Set this to be a string (default none) to have the database add an index for 
     * this field with this name. You do not need to specify the {@link #index()} 
     * boolean as well. To index multiple fields together in one index, each of
     * the fields should have the same indexName value.
     */
    String indexName() default "";
```

But I don't see how to use the same field in two different indexes.